# Can XtraDB be enabled on MariaDB 10.2

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.2, xtradb

**Can we create a table in MariaDB 10.2 with XtraDB engine?**

I have installed MariaDB **10.2** and I am trying to create a table with storage engine XtraDB and I am getting error

*mysql> CREATE TABLE `T1`(`ID` smallint(6),`NAME` varchar(30)) ENGINE=XtraDB;

*ERROR 1286 (42000): **Unknown storage engine** 'XtraDB'*

If I lists the engines of MariaDB here, there are no XtraDB engine type available.

Part of show engines output:

[image]

Comment: Well it was changed as this [answer says](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/changes-improvements-in-mariadb-102/). It will still be `ENGINE=Innodb` when you create tables. Did you try [these instructions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/using-innodb-instead-of-xtradb/)

Comment: Thank you, This means MariaDB is not allowing XtraDB to be used beyond 10.2.  Is this my understanding correct?

Comment: Its still there as a plugin in 10.2. Its removed in 10.3

Comment: @danblack can you guide me how this plugin can be enabled or installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, the answer is no, you can't use XtraDB in MariaDB 10.2. From the [Changes & Improvements in MariaDB 10.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/changes-improvements-in-mariadb-102/) page:

> XtraDB in 10.2 is not up to date with the latest features of InnoDB and cannot be used. As the InnoDB on disk format is identical to XtraDB's this will not cause any problems when upgrading to MariaDB 10.2. See [Why does MariaDB 10.2 use InnoDB instead of XtraDB?](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/why-does-mariadb-102-use-innodb-instead-of-xtradb/)